# Caesar Cipher Translating Incorrectly

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

The Caesar Cipher offset is 21 and the alphabet is "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789."

For example "Xvzcvb" Should be Equal to "Caesar", but instead, the output is "CaeNaM"

```
ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789."

def decrpytstr(message):
    #declare variables
    newString = str()
    ALPHABET = int()
    oneLetter = str()
    newAlphabetValue = int()
    #loop to assign new alphabet value
    for index in range(0, len(message)):
        oneLetter = message[index]
        ALPHABET = ord(oneLetter)

        #assinging new alphabet value
        newAlphabetValue = ALPHABET - 21
        #creating the new string
        newString = newString + chr(newAlphabetValue)
    
    return newString


def main():
    message = input("Enter text: ")
    decrpytstr(message)
    newString = decrpytstr(message)
    print(newString)
    input("Press ENTER to exit")
main()
```

Comment: Who told you you have to declare variables? Python is dynamically typed, so you can skip straight to defining.

Comment: habit from C++ @wjandrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems

- You're not actually using your original ALPHABET values
- You don't account for upper case characters
- We need to wrap round so that we always find something in the alphabet when we subtract the magic 21 steps

Correcting these gives us something like this...

```
ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789."

def decrpytstr(message):
    newString = ''
    #loop to assign new alphabet value
    for index in range(0, len(message)):
        oneLetter = message[index]

        #assinging new alphabet value
        newAlphabetValue = (ALPHABET.find(oneLetter.lower()) - 21) % len(ALPHABET) + (ord('A') if oneLetter.isupper() else ord('a'))
        #creating the new string
        newString = newString + chr(newAlphabetValue)
    
    return newString


def main():
    message = input("Enter text: ")
    decrpytstr(message)
    newString = decrpytstr(message)
    print(newString)
    input("Press ENTER to exit")
main()
```

Comment: Line 15- 
if oneLetter == ' ':
            newAlphabetValue = 32
Do you think that is the best solution for the white spaces? @robert-longson

Comment: I think that's a different question because your question and testcase don't talk about what to do with spaces. If you have a solution I guess you don't need to ask one though.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.asciitable.com/
As I see the ascii table, the value of b `98` will be M `77` by decrementing 21. I guess you have to deal with uppercase and lowercase separately.

[Editted] I don't fully understand what you want to achieve, but how about this?

```
ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

def decrpytstr(message):
    new_string = ""
    for i in range(len(message)):
        character = message[i]
        new_character = ALPHABET[ALPHABET.find(character) - 21 % 26]
        new_string = new_string + new_character
    return new_string


def main():
    message = input("Enter text: ")
    decrpytstr(message)
    newString = decrpytstr(message)
    print(newString)
    input("Press ENTER to exit")
main()
```

```
Enter text: xvznvm
caesar
Press ENTER to exit
```

Comment: I thought if I made a global variable for the alphabet. I would not be using the ASCII table. But I see what you mean and you are correct.